# Camel-Restlet producer message body is null

Tags: apache-camel

When invoking a rest endpoint using camel-restlet, the post body is not set.
Here is my blueprint.xml

```
<camelContext id="blueprint-bean-context-SF"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

    <route id="Camel-Restlet-Client">

        <from uri="timer://example?repeatCount=1&amp;period=1000" />
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="api-key">
            <constant>{{drupal-api-key}}</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setBody><constant>{name: "paul rudd", movies: ["I Love You Man", "Role Models"]}</constant></setBody>
        <log message="Request: ${headers} \n ${body}" />
        <to uri="restlet:https://reqres.in/api/users?restletMethod=POST" />
        <log message="Response: ${headers} \n ${body}" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

I am using camel 2.20.1. Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to cmel myself, but i would guess the problem is the setHeader you are using. Because setHeader sets the header of the Camel-Message, not the header of the http-request which gets send over the wire. You would need to set a header on the message, that would be known by restlet. And restlet would transport the value of the setheader to the theader of the http-request.

Sorry but I dont how to do that. The following coding works, using the Header for authentification:

```
restConfiguration("restlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json); // use json for all

from("timer://example?repeatCount=1&period=1000")
.setHeader("CamelRestletLogin", constant("xxx"))
.setHeader("CamelRestletPassword", constant("xxx"))
.to("restlet:https://xxx.hana.ondemand.com:443/ain/services/api/v1/models")
```

Sry I couldnt help more.